# DTOs and WCF RIA

Tags: wcf, ria, automapper, dto

I have a DTO which has a collection within it of another DTO which I populate server-side and send to the client. However, this inner DTO collection is not returned to the client.

I believe I need to use the [Include] and [Association] attributes so that WCF RIA services knows what to do, however my issue with this is there is no real association as such between the main DTO and the inner DTO collection, I am just using it to aggregate data from various sources for return to the client.

Is my understanding wrong in what I am trying to achieve, if not how do I get WCF RIA to send this inner DTO collection.

I should add that I am using automapper and want to achieve it using such.

Here is an example, I want to send back to the client in one chunk;

1. The competencies that the employee has.
2. The competencies that the employee requires for their job.
3. The GAP, which is the difference between 1 and 2.

> ```
> public class CompetencyRequirementsDto
> {
>     [Key]
>     public string CompanyId { get; set; }
>     [Key]
>     public string EmployeeNo { get; set; }
>
>     public string JobId { get; set; }
>
>     [Include]
>     [Association("EmployeeCompetencies","CompanyId, EmployeeNo","CompanyId, EmployeeNo")]
>     public IList<EmployeeCompetencyDto> EmployeeCompetencies { get; set; }
>     [Include]
>     [Association("JobCompetencies","JobId, CompanyId","JobId, CompanyId")]
>     public IList<JobCompetencyDto> JobCompetencies { get; set; }
>     [Include]
>     [Association("CompetencyGap", "JobId, CompanyId", "JobId, CompanyId")]
>     public IList<JobCompetencyDto> CompetencyGap { get; set; }
> } }
> ```

Now item 1 works fine, but 2 and 3 don't? What I have found is that my DTO is created ok server side but when it gets to the client CompetencyGap(even when it has no values) has
been given JobCompetencies values.

Comment: perhaps if you included some code?  Did you generate the ria services or write them yourself?  Did you use linq2sql or entity framework?

Comment: The ria services has been generated with a bit of hand crafting, this is more of a general question on how to use DTO with RIA in the true sense of a DTO i.e. a bucket of data where the data within is not neccessarily all related, but as far as I can see any inner DTO needs to be associated with the parent DTO. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show any code? Perhaps try to replicate problem with a simpler set of DTO objects and paste that?

Comment: I'm still confused.  Why have a custom DTO collection?  Why not return IQueryable<myDTO> or List<myDTO>?  What does your query look like to get the data from the database?

Comment: Can you provide the query method of the domain service that returns the data

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ADO.Net Entity data model and using RIA Services against them then you have got an option to create associated metadata.

So to get the reference entities at you client side we need to modify both the our corresponding meta-data and as well as well the function of the domain service class which is fetching your data .

```
Here I am giving an example...

1. Just add [Include] attribute at the the top of  the referenced data for example.

[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(Customer.CustomerMetadata))]
    public partial class Customer
    {

        // This class allows you to attach custom attributes to properties
        // of the Customer class.
        //
        // For example, the following marks the Xyz property as a
        // required property and specifies the format for valid values:
        //    [Required]
        //    [RegularExpression("[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*")]
        //    [StringLength(32)]
        //    public string Xyz { get; set; }
        internal sealed class CustomerMetadata
        {

            // Metadata classes are not meant to be instantiated.
            private CustomerMetadata()
            {
            }

            public int CustomerID { get; set; }

            public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

            public string FullName { get; set; }

            [Include]
            public EntityCollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }

            public string Password { get; set; }
        }
    }


2. Modify the function in the domain service and add include there also for example. 

     public IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomers()
        {
             var res = this.ObjectContext.Customers.Include("Orders");
             return res;
        }

  In your case the first part is done you just need to modify your domain service query to get reference entities.
```